# SpriteKitでテクスチャー同士の間に隙間が空いてしまう。

Tags: swift, ios, spritekit

お世話になります。

textureとして、不透明な四角いpng画像を使っています。
＜画像２＞のように、画像ファイルは色のついた部分だけなのですが、spriteにすると、
並んだ時に＜画像１＞のように隙間が空いてしまいます。
隙間を設定するプロパティなどあるのでしょうか？

---

＜画像１＞
[image: ＜画像１＞]

[GameScene.swift]

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let ballCount = 3
    let accelerationSpeed : CGFloat = 5
    let textureCount : UInt32 = 4

    var textures = [SKTexture]()

    let texture_left = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Frame_left")
    let texture_right = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Frame_right")

    var motionManager: CMMotionManager!

    var ballXposition : Double = 0
    var ballYposition : Double = 0

    var accelerationX : Double = 0
    var accelerationY : Double = 0




    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        for i in 0..<textureCount {
            let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ball_\(i+1)")
            textures.append(texture)
        }

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zero
        self.physicsWorld.speed = 1.0

        self.size = CGSize(width: 320, height: 568)

        setupObjects()

        motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main){data,_ in
            self.accelerationX = data!.acceleration.x
            self.accelerationY = data!.acceleration.y
        }
    }


    func setupObjects() {

        //壁
        let sprite_left = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture_left)
        let sprite_right = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture_right)

        sprite_left.position = CGPoint(x: 80, y: 284)
        sprite_right.position = CGPoint(x: 240, y: 284)

        sprite_left.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture_left, size: sprite_left.size)
        sprite_left.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        sprite_left.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1 << 0
        sprite_left.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1 << 1
        sprite_left.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.9

        sprite_right.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture_right, size: sprite_right.size)
        sprite_right.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        sprite_right.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1 << 0
        sprite_right.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1 << 1
        sprite_right.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.9

        self.addChild(sprite_left)
        self.addChild(sprite_right)

        //Ball
        for i in 0..<ballCount {
            let textureRand = Int(arc4random_uniform(textureCount))
            let ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: textures[textureRand])
            ball.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
            ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.5+CGFloat(i)*0.1)
            self.addChild(ball)

            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: textures[textureRand], size: CGSize(width: ball.size.width*1, height: ball.size.height*1))

            ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1 << 1
            ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1 << 0 | 1 << 1
        }
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: CGFloat(self.accelerationX)*accelerationSpeed, dy: CGFloat(self.accelerationY)*accelerationSpeed)
    }


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("Contact!")
    }
}
```

[GameViewController.swift]

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

            let scene = GameScene()
            scene.size = view.frame.size
            print(scene.size)

            view.presentScene(scene)
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

「Frame_right」はグリーンの縁の部分の画像です。

＜画像２＞
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: あなたが貼り付けられたpng画像を使用して、画面上に2個の`SKSpriteNode`を並べて、重量任せに落っことしたのですが、細い黒い筋が見えているものの(物理計算の誤差のせいでしょうか?)、あなたの画面キャプチャーにあるような状態は再現できませんでした。画像のような状態を再現するのに必要十分なコードとなるようギリギリまでコードを絞り込んだ上で、コード全体をお示しいただくことはできるでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！質問にコードを追加しました。

Comment: コードのご提示ありがとうございます。私としては画像情報(texture)から輪郭を検出する際の誤差が1point程度出るようなアルゴリズムを使用しているのではないかと思うのですが、残念ながら確実なことはわからず、誤差を小さくして精度を高めるようなパラメーターも発見できませんでした。直接の回答とは言えないので申し訳ないのですが、「誤差」を小さくするためのヒント等を回答の形にまとめさせていただきますので、ご覧おきください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントに示しましたが、`SKPhysicsBody.init(texture:size:)`が内部的に使用する輪郭抽出のアルゴリズムでは1point程度の誤差が出るようになっているのではないかと思います。

画像データの中身が真四角であれば、もう少し精度の高い検出ができそうにも思いますが、そう言う場合には`SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf:)`を使うべきなので、特殊な場合の結果だけ最適化するようなことはしていないのだと思われます。

(「思います」「思われます」ばかりで申し訳ありません。)

さて、少し精度を高めるための工夫ですが、Ballについては以下のようなコードを試してみてください。

```
    //Ball
    for i in 0..<ballCount {
        let textureRand = Int(arc4random_uniform(textureCount))
        let ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: textures[textureRand])
        //### ball.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30) //<-ここではサイズを指定せず
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.5+CGFloat(i)*0.1)
        self.addChild(ball)

        //### texture本来のサイズのままで輪郭を抽出する
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: textures[textureRand], size: textures[textureRand].size())

        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1 << 1
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1 << 0 | 1 << 1

        ball.scale(to: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)) //<-ここでスケールを指定して所望の大きさにする
    }
```

元画像サイズは200x200ですから、その画像で1point程度の誤差が出ても、表示サイズの30x30まで縮小すれば、誤差も縮小され目立たなくなると言うのを狙っています。

(目立たなくしたせいというよりも物理計算の限界ですが、最初のコメントに示したような「細い黒い筋」は残ってしまうかもしれません。)

なお、物理形状が長方形とわかっているなら`SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf:)`を、円形とわかっているなら`SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:)`を使用した方が、一般的には高速かつ高精度に物理形状を表すことができます。

---

`sprite_left`と`sprite_right`については画像データがないので試していませんが、こちらも長方形だとわかっているのであれば、`SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf:)`を使ったり、長方形の組み合わせなのであれば、`SKPhysicsBody.init(bodies:)`を使うと言う手もあります。

最終的にはどのようなやり方があなたの目的に一番合うのかはわかりませんが、お試しください。

Comment: とても丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます！試してみます！